# How can I display column names of one table in a combobox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

In vb.net 2008, how can I display table column names in a combobox?

In SQL I have a Document table and there are columns in this table like Doc_id, Size, Path.

The combobox must display the columns name like

**doc_id** in the first line, **size** in the second line, **path** in the last line

Comment: do you need that a combo box should display all three column in one like Doc_id,Size,Path

Comment: no no .. the combobox must list columns name

Comment: i mean that you need that combo box should display (((Doc_id,Size,Path))  at first position. if not then kindly explain your question

Comment: combobox <<< when you open the combobox must display

doc_id in the first line , size in the second line ,path in the last line

Comment: can you share your code where you are binding with combobox ?

Comment: myConnection.Open()
        'Fill(ComboBox)
        Dim strSQL As String = "select * FROM Document"
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Document")

        With ComboBox1
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("Document")
            .DisplayMember =*** here i want the columns name ****


            .SelectedIndex = 0
        End With

        myConnection.Close()

Comment: does your Document table contains only three column (Doc_id,Size,Path)

Comment: no it's contains more 3 column

Comment: can c# code will work for you, if i give demo there

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little too late since I see this thing is about eight years old, but I just ran into this issue where I had to do exactly what the initial questioner was asking for. Since I resolved it, I will leave it here just incase another poor sap like us comes along looking for answers
'VB.net

```
    Dim ds As DataSet =   <define your dataset here>
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(<Your tablename here>)
    For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        combobox1.Items.Add(column.ColumnName)
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks.... I posted it right after it worked. 
I have a bad habit of adding tostring function and didnt think about it....
I will modify the code here  ~Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion , i will suggest you not to bind the combobox directly with the `DataTalble`. you can bind it by looping all the row of the `DataTable`. you use following  snipped as a reference:

```
    Dim objDataTable As DataTable = ds.Tables("Document")
 IF objDataTable <> NULL Then
 For j As Integer = 0 To objDataTable.Rows.Count
    Dim str As String = objDataTable.Rows(j)("Doc_id").ToString()
    comboBox1.Items.Add(str)

    str = objDataTable.Rows(j)("Size").ToString()
    comboBox1.Items.Add(str)

    str = objDataTable.Rows(j)("Path").ToString()
    comboBox1.Items.Add(str)
Next
END IF
```

Hope this will work for you ;)

Comment: i get this error " Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on this line  "For j As Integer = 0 To objDataTable.Rows.Count - 1"

Comment: it means that Datatable is not being filled up from DataSet, Kindly debug the code and check...

Comment: make sure that these code will be added after filling the DataSet

Comment: here the code but still the same error ..  Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim objDataTable As DataTable = ds.Tables("Document")
        For j As Integer = 0 To objDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim str As String = objDataTable.Rows(j)("Doc_id").ToString()
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(str)

            str = objDataTable.Rows(j)("Size").ToString()
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(str)

            str = objDataTable.Rows(j)("Path").ToString()
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(str)
        Next

Comment: on this line "For j As Integer = 0 To objDataTable.Rows.Count - 1"

Comment: you dont have to check for objDataTable.Rows.Count - 1, its objDataTable.Rows.Count, Kindly go through updated code

Comment: IF block has been added and loop checking till  objDataTable.Rows.Count only